# Compilation error - Static member

Tags: c++, static-methods

I have a class definition with a **virtual** method.

On compiling I get the error that  `'MethodType Class::Method'` is not a static member of **class** `Class`

The most popular solution I have found is to add the keyword **static** to the Method definition in the header file.

However, the method is defined as **virtual**. So to add the **static** keyword I will have to remove the **virtual** keyword. Unfortunately that cannot be done as the class inherits from a parent where this method is also declared **virtual**, leading to another compiler error. (Please note, I'm using defined interfaces and have no access to the parent class's source code)

Does anyone have any ideas?

---

Header file:

```
class X : public OtherClass
{
   public:
      X();
      ~X();  

     virtual structType MethodName(ParamType1,ParamType2);

};
```

Then in the CPP file I have:

```
structType * X::MethodName(ParamType1 P1, ParamType2 P2)
{
   //Implementation here
}
```

And that gets flagged with error:

```
'structType* X::MethodName' is not a static member of 'class X'
```

Comment: We need to see your class definition. At present I cannot tell what you are asking.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. If the base function that you're overriding is `virtual`, removing the keyword `virtual` from the derived function that overrides it does _not_ result in a compile error; in fact it does nothing at all!

Comment: Could you provide some code? Most possibly you call the method like a static method, not like an instance one.

Comment: "The most popular solution I have found is to add the keyword static to the Method definition in the header file.", "So to add the static keyword I will have to remove the virtual keyword." - please spend time and learn the concepts behind these keywords, these are not random on/off switches to get the code to compile.

Comment: @Laurynas Biveinis:
I understand the concepts behind the keyword, and as I said if I remove the 'virtual' keyword, beyond all reason I get yet another error.
'Method cannot be declared since vitrual Method declared in base class"

Comment: @GreatCthulhu: Is this Visual C++ 6.0 by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Finally. In the implementation of MethodName1

```
     structType * X::MethodName(ParamType1 P1, ParamType2 P2)
```

ParamType1 was a non-standard type. It is actually a class in the underlying application 
to which I have only the API.

Turns out that the implemtation for class ParamType1 was missing / not compiled / something.

The problem with linking was not to do with the class I loaded, even though it would appear as such because of the line the compiler provided.
So for future reference, when using classes and struct in a function definition, keep an eye out for this linking error.

Thanks for the assist again everyone.

Answer (score 3):

You have to make it `static` if you want to call the method *without an object of that class*. This makes no sense for virtual methods.
You must create an object of that class, and then call the method.

```
struct X {
   static int bar();
   int foo();

};

X::bar(); // Works, static method called
X::foo(); // Doesn't work (your problem)

X x;
x.bar(); // Works, but X::bar() recommended (so that one sees that it's static...)
x.foo(); // Works, your solution
```

Comment: And it's not called a "method".

Comment: @centro and @Tomalak Geret'kal:

class X : public OtherClass
{
   public:
      X();
      ~X();  

     virtual structType MethodName(ParamType1,ParamTYpe2);

};

Then in the CPP file I have:

structType * X::MethodName(ParamType1 P1, ParamType2 P2)
{
   //Implementation here
}

And that gets flagged with error:
'structType* X::MethodName' is not a static member of 'class X'

Comment: @GreaetCthulhu: Edit it into the question please. The class definition, how you're using it, what you expect, and what you actually see. We don't know what the question is.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a parsing error.

Your class definition says:

```
class X : public OtherClass {
   public:
      X();
     ~X();
     virtual structType MethodName(ParamType1,ParamTYpe2);
};
```

But your definition for `MethodName` has a different return type:

```
structType* X::MethodName(ParamType1 P1, ParamType2 P2) {
    //Implementation here
}
```

The compiler's not really sure what to make of that, and thinks you're trying to do something with a non-existent static member, for some reason.

The solution is to fix your function definition and declaration so that the function has one, single, consistent return type. Either `structType` or `structType*`.

Comment: Thanks for the assist.
I fixed so the two return types match (that was a stupid oversight on my part). However the compiler is still telling me that X::MethodName is not a statis member of class X.

Comment: Newest update:
I got frustrated and moved the files to a backup space. 
I created new files and copied the code from the old files to the new. They compile perfectly fine.

This made me suspiscious so I compiled the new files on two other machines, without problem. When I move the old files to the other machines, they still fail to compile.

I thought I must've missed something in the copying so I used diff to check the old vs. new files and diff reports no differences.

I think it's safe to write this one off as weird Unix voodoo.
Thanks for the assist all.

Comment: @GreatCthulhu: Please write your solution as an answer to the question, and accept it.

Comment: I can't do so within the first 8 hours of posting my question as I have less than 100 rep. Will do that as soon as I can though. 

Thanks for your help and apologies for wasting your time on this.